# Transcendental equation analytical solving

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I want to solve a transcendental equation analytically,
the equation basically is

```
Solve[-2.50663 gs gv ((kb mc T)/h^2)^0.5 PolyLog[1/2, -E^y] == 
  1.25331 gs gv ((kb mc T)/
    h^2)^0.5 (-PolyLog[1/2, -E^x] - PolyLog[1/2, -E^(-vd + x)]), y]
```

I want to solve for y and get it in terms of the other variables. I can't plot and find the solution since I am looking for analytical answer. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: `Reduce` is sometimes more powerful than `Solve` for non-polynomial problems. If we assume a few things about your problem then your problem "simplifies" down to `Reduce[PolyLog[1/2,-E^y]==c,y]` for a complicated expression `c`, but it replies "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce".

Comment: @Bill then how should I go about next?

Comment: Look into the literature on PolyLog and see if there are any known inverses. Since Plot[PolyLog[1/2,-E^y],{y,-10,10}] looks nice and simple and Real then could you possibly express this as an infinite series and get a solution that way? Ask very bright and experienced mathematicians if they are aware of any ways to get analytical solutions to your problem. I know of nothing else.